# How to get the width and the height in glium?

Tags: rust, glium

I'm using glium in Rust. I want to get the width and the height.

I can't write and understand English well, because I'm Japanese. Maybe my English has some problems so I'm sorry.

Comment: Width and height of what? Of the OpenGL context?

Comment: I want to get the width and the height of the window. (Sorry. I searched about the OpenGL context because I don't know it. But I can't understand the OpenGL context.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `glium`, and I say OpenGL context, because OpenGL doesn't know **anything** about windows. I searched for documentation, and maybe in glium you can use [`get_framebuffer_dimensions`](https://docs.rs/glium/0.30.1/glium/backend/glutin/struct.Display.html#method.get_framebuffer_dimensions)

Comment: Thank you. Can you write the comment in the answer section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments section, there's a [`Display::get_framebuffer_dimensions`](https://docs.rs/glium/0.30.1/glium/backend/glutin/struct.Display.html#method.get_framebuffer_dimensions), so if you have the `glium::Display` object around, you can extract the dimensions of the OpenGL context using it.

> `pub fn get_framebuffer_dimensions(&self) -> (u32, u32)`
>
> Calls `get_framebuffer_dimensions` on the backend object stored by this context.